# How do you truncate a String to a max number of bytes in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, byte, truncate

I am parsing a JSON object obtained by `URLFetchApp.fetch()` and need to truncate a string value to a max number of bytes. It seems like some combination of the Google Apps Script `Utilities Class` and `HTTPResponse Class` is where I will find the answer, but I can not figure out which methods to use and how to put them together.

```
{object: {key: 'string'}}
```

something like:

```
object.key.string.toBytes().substringAsBytes(0,maxBytes).backToString()
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response

Answer (score 1):

Use with [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
const str = { obj: { key: 'string' } }.obj.key,
  maxBytes = 10,
  byteData = Utilities.newBlob(str).getBytes();
byteData.splice(maxBytes);
const truncatedStr = Utilities.newBlob(byteData).getDataAsString();
```